# How to add uipickerview selected row value on uilabel?

Tags: ios

I am working on `uipicker` inside `uitableview's prototype cell` where I create a `uilabel`. Now I add the picker view row selected value on label, but my problem is that when I select row from picker view then all the label are updated.

Value should be updated on selected row on `uilabel`. Here is my code and screen shot.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return  [myData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *lable = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:111];
    lable.tag = indexPath.row;
    lable.text = value;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _nameLabel.text =nil;

    [self.mytableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]  withRowAnimation:NO];

    [self bringUpPickerViewWithRow:indexPath];
}



- (void)bringUpPickerViewWithRow:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *currentCellSelected = [self.mytableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^
     {
         self.pickerView.hidden = NO;
         self.pickerView.center = (CGPoint)    { currentCellSelected.frame.size.width/2, self.mytableview.frame.origin.y + currentCellSelected.frame.size.height*4};


         self.mytableview.separatorStyle =  UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
         [self.mytableview setNeedsDisplay];
     }
                     completion:nil];


}

- (void)hidePickerView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^
     {
         self.pickerView.center = (CGPoint){160, 800};
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         self.pickerView.hidden = YES;
         [self.mytableview reloadData];
     }];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView   *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return  _countingarray.count;
}



- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    [self.mytableview reloadData];
    [self hidePickerView];
    NSLog(@"row selected:%ld", (long)row);
    NSString *resultString = _countingarray[row];

    value = resultString;
}


- (NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:  (NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row+1];
    return _countingarray[row];
}

- (IBAction)editbuttonclicked:(id)sender {

    if([self.mytableview isEditing] == NO){

        //[self.mytableview settitle:@"Done"];
        //set the table to editing mode
        [self.mytableview setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }else

    {

        //we are currently in editing mode
        //change the button text back to Edit
        //[self.editbutton setTitle:@"Edit"];
        //take the table out of edit mode
        [self.mytableview setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:  (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [myData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.mytableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}
```

[image: this is my screen shot when i select 2 from picker view at first cell than all the uilabel updates same value]

Comment: you already have a `myData` which you use to determine how many rows should be shown in the tableView, you should probably us whatever is in that array to determine the text shown for each label. After you did this you longer should need `value` but should only manipulate the data in that array and `reloadData` afterwards.

Comment: how the value is declared ?

Comment: @luk2302  can you tell me how will i add values using myData.

Comment: The same way you remove some objects from the array in the end of your post, you can replace or add objects in the array.

Comment: thanks for your response. @mihirmehta NSString *value; this is how i declared value.

Comment: try using self.value instead at both places ...

Comment: @mihirmehta plz check my screenshot

Comment: @luk2302 can you edit my code for resolve this issue plz.

Comment: @sandeeptomar suggested code in below answer. Test it and let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: @sandeeptomar you are reloading your tableData two times when you select row of UIPickerView i.e. in didSelectRow and hidePickerView method.

Comment: @sandeeptomar You need to modify  array which you provided datasource for tableview

Comment: can you please provide me some code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing. "value" is global variable, so when you reload your table view , this code gets called for every cell in tableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UILabel *lable = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:111];
lable.tag = indexPath.row;
lable.text = value;
return cell;
}
```

Now notice

```
label.text= value
```

For every cell your label get same value(whatever it is).

@luk2302 is correct. Manage this within you myData.

**Suggested Solution**
There could be number of ways to do this. This is what I can suggest right away

Don't have value as global variable.
Add NSIndexPath *currentCellPath as global variable.

Now in you didSelectRow do this

```
     -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    currentCellPath = indexPath;
    // remaining code goes here
     _nameLabel.text =nil;

     [self.mytableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]  withRowAnimation:NO];

     [self bringUpPickerViewWithRow:indexPath];
   }
```

Now in your picker's didselectRow do this

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTableView cellForIndexPath:currentCellPath];
 cell.label.text = _countingarray[row];
  [self.mytableview reloadData];
  [self hidePickerView];
  NSLog(@"row selected:%ld", (long)row);
  //NSString *resultString = _countingarray[row]; // remove this

  //value = resultString; //romove this
```

}

Comment: its gives me error for tableview and label like that :-  "  no visible interface for uitableview declares the selector cellforindexpath". and the another error for table;-  "property label not found on object of type "uitableviewcell" ".

Comment: my bad, first use '[self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:currentCellPath]'

Comment: and please tell my why you have to assign tag to you Label(111) and change it your indexPath.

Comment: because i will create 111 tableview cell in mytableview.